# Rounded Image cutting form all side

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, game-development, cocos2d-android

I am creating a game in cocos2d-android.
all the images i use in Sprite shows me proper output except rounded image.

Rounded images are cut from all the side.

i test same image in cocos2d-iPhone, which shows me perfect output.

How to solve this rounded image issue.

**EDIT :**

**Actual Image:**

[image: Actual Image]

**Result Image:**

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Could you provide an example image to show the probelem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the **issue is there in cocos-2d source code**.
But as a temporary solution, you can modify that image with `5px transparent border`.
And try to use that new image. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

seems size is not proper . use dip and `scaleType fitXY` if its imageView . or recalculate and reset  x,y cordinates if drawing bitmap or canvas

Comment: as i mention i am working with cocos2d-android framework
so i am not using canvas
and i am simply using original image. i am not scaling or starching image.

Comment: Do you provide images for the different resolutions of android phones?

Comment: currently i am targeting for one resolution only.
it looks there is some problem in cocos2d-android source code.